# Fragments overlapping when I am using fragmentTransaction.add method

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, fragment

I am facing some weird issue with fragments, I am displaying google map on these two fragments, while switching from `Home Fragment` to `Request cab` fragment, in `Request cab` fragment, fragments are overlapping, I can see `Home Fragment` in background and its also clickable I can move map of `Home Fragment` too. This issue occur when I use `fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame, fragment, fragmenttag);`
 but if I use replace then its working fine, but I want to get the view back `onBackPressed` that is not possible with replacing the fragmnet. I am attaching screenshots and code.

```
 public void changeFragment(final Fragment fragment, final String fragmenttag) {
    try {
        drawer_close();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame, fragment, fragmenttag);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

[image: Home Fragment]

[image: Request Cab Fragment]

Comment: Try [`hide(Fragment)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction#hide(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment)) home fragment in the transaction as well.

Comment: you just need to setbackground in second fragment or add your second fragment xml I will add answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You just need to add background when you add fragment.

```
add(): adds the new fragment on the top of another fragment that's why you can see below fragment

replace(): removes everything then adds the new fragment
```

Answer (score -1):

add and replace work quite differently, while replace removes current fragment from inflated view group. add method just adds new layout inside of ViewGroup. thats why you can see your fragment and thats why its clickable just think them as normal views and not fragments. now you could just add white background to root layout of second fragment and make it clickable it should solve all your problems.